# How to get word between two specific character and list it in vb .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a string and I want to get the words in parentheses and list them:

```
I'm (Kid J)
From (Detroit), (Michigan)
```

I tried the cod below, but this code only lists two words :

```
       For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
            Dim i As Integer = line.IndexOf("(")
            Dim f As String = line.Substring(i + 1, line.IndexOf(")", i - 1) - i - 1)
            TextBox2.AppendText(f + vbCrLf)
       Next
```

the result with this cod is this:

```
Kid J  
Detroit
```

Comment: For each line, you need to run a second (inner) loop. A while loop with an `Exit While` loop when the returned index is -1 would do. Alternatively, you could use Regex if this isn't an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex:

```
Dim text = "I'm (Kid J)
    From (Detroit), (Michigan)"
Dim matches = From match In Regex.Matches(text, "\(([^)]*)\)")
              Select match.Groups(1).Value
Console.Write(String.Join(",", matches))
```

outputs:

```
Kid J,Detroit,Michigan
```

Here's the regex with some explanations:
https://regex101.com/r/13ME3n/1

Comment: Probably better to use `.*?` or `[^)\r\n]*` to avoid matches that span multiple lines.

Comment: Dear, Tim Schmelter this code is great. This is exactly what I was looking for. You are the best, thank you very much